# MultiPolygon Filtering in Shapely

Tags: intersection, shapely

I have a large set `S: List[Polygon]` (Shapely `Polygon`s), and a `mask: MultiPolygon`.
I want to filter out all of the polygons in `S` that intersect with `mask`.

I can write: `S2 = [p for p in S if not mask.intersects(p)]`.

However, to speed things up I was wondering if there was a way to do it without the list comprehension and as a single operation so that the internal Shapely/GEOS search may be done more efficiently. Essentially like running a `mask.intersection(MultiPolygon(S))` but without the added cost of getting the actual intersections of each sub-polygon (and while maintaining the original input order).
Ideally it would return something like a `List[bool]` indicating the results per sub-polygon in `S`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answering myself after finding the solution - may be of help to others.]

Shapely supports [**Prepared Geometry Operations**](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#prepared-geometry-operations) where *"Shapely geometries can be processed into a state that supports more efficient batches of operations*".